# How to improve the efficiency and performance of this SQL select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

This script is very slow. How can I make it faster? It is being run against a large set of data.

I need to find instances where a group of fields are expected to have the same values but don't.

Here's a succinct example of the query:

```
CREATE TABLE #Example ( ID int, UserID int, ColA char(1), ColB char(1), ColC char(1), ColD  char(1))
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (1, 1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (2, 1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (3, 1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (4, 1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (5, 1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'X');

SELECT   UserID, ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM  ( SELECT DISTINCT a.UserID, a.ColA, a.ColB, a.ColC, a.ColD FROM #Example a ) x
GROUP BY UserID, ColA, ColB, ColC
HAVING COUNT(ColD) > 1
```

As is, this returns 1 row, which is what I want, it's just slow. If the X in row 5 was a D then 0 rows returned.

Comment: Have you looked at indexes for the table? Even for temporary tables, indexes help.

Comment: I'll review the indexes. The table and indexes have been rebuilt today so they're fresh.

Comment: How do you "rebuild" the table?  Do you TRUNCATE the table?  DELETE some/all records from the table?  Do you UPDATE some/all records? etc.

Comment: We have a raw data file from a vendor we're bringing in to our database. Import, review, tweak the import script, truncate, re-import. That's how.

Comment: I would investigate that "import" process a bit.  Is every row in the table a separate INSERT statement?  If so, is every INSERT statement within its own transaction?  Ideally, you want a single transaction for the entire "import" process.  If it's not a prod db, you can further help things by changing the recovery  model to SIMPLE.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if I misunderstood.  :(
Is it the SELECT query that is slow?  Or the table population?  If it's not the table population, disregard my comment above.

Comment: It's the SELECT. It's going to be used a lot and I'd just like it to be faster. I have a feeling there's a much better way of writing that query.

Comment: I really doubt it would be any faster, but if you are trying only to determine for which `UserID` there are existing disparate column values based on a specific set of columns, you could perhaps do something like select one row per UserID using MIN or MAX and then for these run an EXISTS query to check wheter there are existing rows for that UserID which do not have the same column properties. `NOT EXISTS` will short circuit, so perhaps there is hope... https://gist.github.com/plalx/b74bde10bb7a24da951e

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's faster, but here is the same query as yours written more succinctly.  I don't think you need the subquery.

```
SELECT  UserID, ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM    #Example a
GROUP BY UserID, ColA, ColB, ColC
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ColD) > 1;
```

Comment: What about disrepencies in other columns?